# Any example of validate<Key>:error: method?

Tags: ios, core-data

Hello I'm reading a Core Data Programming Guide.
[On Managing the object life-cycle > Object Validation > Implementing Custom Property-Level Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH20-SW1), I have no idea about `validate<Key>:error:` method.

What is that method? Can I get any example?

Comment: The page you link to describes the method and gives an example implementation. What doesn't make sense? If you said you wanted to know about the method, I'd point you to that page. What part(s) are you having trouble with?

Comment: @TomHarrington I just wanted know which apple document has a method that is same as the form(`validate<Key>:error:`). And now, I know `validate<Key>:error:` is kind of example custom method. :D